Sign PDF using iTEXT java with certificate in cloud with no container CMS (naked data)
I am implementing a PDF digital signature process using iText 7 in Java. The workflow requires me to:

Prepare the PDF for signature: Create a visible signature field and generate the hash of the PDF content. This hash will be sent to a cloud signature service.

Receive the signature data: The service returns a JSON containing the signed hash (signedContent), the certificate (encodedX509) and other information.

Finalize the signature: Enter the signature data in the field created previously.


analyzing similar doubts I arrived at this solution which I believe is the most appropriate.
private static byte[] emptySignature(String src, String dest, String fieldname, Certificate[] chain)
        throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException
{
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest), new StampingProperties());

    PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = signer.getSignatureAppearance();
    appearance.setPageRect(new Rectangle(100, 500, 200, 100));
    appearance.setPageNumber(1);
    appearance.setCertificate(chain[0]);
    appearance.setReason("For test");
    appearance.setLocation("HKSAR");
    signer.setFieldName(fieldname);

    PreSignatureContainer external = new PreSignatureContainer(PdfName.Adobe_PPKLite, PdfName.Adbe_pkcs7_detached);
    signer.signExternalContainer(external, 8192);

    return external.getHash();
}

public static class PreSignatureContainer implements IExternalSignatureContainer {
    private final PdfDictionary sigDic;
    private byte[] hash;

    public PreSignatureContainer(PdfName filter, PdfName subFilter) {
        sigDic = new PdfDictionary();
        sigDic.put(PdfName.Filter, filter);
        sigDic.put(PdfName.SubFilter, subFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] sign(InputStream data) throws GeneralSecurityException {
        String hashAlgorithm = "SHA256";
        BouncyCastleDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
        X509Certificate certificate = null;
        Certificate[] certs = null;

        try{
            certificate = getCertificate("cert");
            certs = new Certificate[]{certificate};
        } catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            byte[] hash = DigestAlgorithms.digest(data, digest.getMessageDigest(hashAlgorithm));
            PdfPKCS7 pkcs7 = new PdfPKCS7(null,certs , "SHA-256", null, digest, false);
            byte[] sh = pkcs7.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash,PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS, null, null);
            this.hash = sh;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new GeneralSecurityException("PreSignatureContainer signing exception", e);
        }

        return new byte[0];
    }

    @Override
    public void modifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic) {
        signDic.putAll(sigDic);
    }

    public byte[] getHash() {
        return hash;
    }

byte[] signatureBytes = THE_RETRIEVED_SIGNATURE_BYTES;
byte[] certificateBytes = THE_RETRIEVED_CERTIFICATE_BYTES;

API Response JSON
{   "data": {      "requestId": "01JEE2TDRMZAV8GZTMQPHGTMKJ",      "executionStatus": {         "currentStatus": "COMPLETED-WITH-SIGNATURE",         "requestTimestamp": "2024-12-06T13:33:49.204Z",         "executionTimestamp": "2024-12-06T13:33:49.369Z"      },      "subjectIdentification": {         "identificationKey": "104699xxx",         "identificationType": "CPF"      },      "certificateInformation": {         "serialNumber": "1AADB23286C489B4",         "issuerName": "C=BR\nO=ICP-Brasil\nOU=Secretaria da Receita Federal do Brasil - RFB\nCN=AC VALID RFB v5",         "validity": {            "notBefore": "Oct 28 21:23:44 2023 GMT",            "notAfter": "Oct 26 21:23:44 2028 GMT"         },         "subjectName": "C=BR\nO=ICP-Brasil\nOU=Secretaria da Receita Federal do Brasil - RFB\nOU=RFB e-CPF A3\nOU=AC VALID RFB V5\nOU=AR CFM\nOU=Presencial\nOU=33583550000130\nCN=GESxxxxx:1046998xxx",         "encodedX509": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\n41LnKzM8WzI3NPwXC9Nq\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n",         "fingerprint256": "EE:9E:F4:78:9D:93:4D:2B:77:AC:08:FE:5D:36:C4:27:6A:EB:73:C1:C2:C0:69:FA:BA:94:7D:51:CA:5F:B5:54",         "subjectAlternatives": "email:gexxx@gesxnxxxxx.com.br"      },      "signatures": [         {            "signatureId": "01JEE2TDRMBVMPHKM8S2AWQ2S0",            "contentId": "1",            "contentDigest": "NgiGYmzUlAf0xLNDTdQQGP7XdPzrNDjgClsgA3fcpVA=",            "contentDescription": "DOCUMENTO_PDF",            "signedContent": "vyBnlyq4Plv4lUkaSwpUUmIjGXKZaY6yYnjUmiZA4UH0ypTLF7zgoi+O2i87kVyjMiO/mZ1JcOxIQpepD8dgFyWBA8Sn8g4IrTFfIe8dYQPy8v6zqZyYTXg+Rywupd6Qqo4wWEyay0p/7tnTVSCTA1YJLsVuvOAWc291gG6jdy0w39H+3dBYl1dAhtz6qExXXX/1eAgVDBw65UfvVzAU6YTM08G6+SrrUdTJgwToILACtW8aFZrIzK4kvXqhHBrF1+hL/85lFstEoNEeXISwR11WBc2Ek9f/YV4yPu9JVmHCUd/QpTyWJ5avnIzMuYR+UJlRNfxZaTYbKAEYlnGeiw==",            "signatureTimestamp": "2024-12-06T13:33:49.369Z",            "extended": {}         }      ]   }}

I have a question about how to generate the CMS container using the data from this JSON that I have as a response from the API. I did not attach any PDFs because all the ones I generated are not complete, as I have not yet been able to generate the CMS container with this data.
I appreciate any help.
Update 1
Right after I posted the question I was able to sign it.
The code looked like this.
Preparing the container
private static String emptySignature(String src, String dest, String fieldname)
        throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest), new StampingProperties());

    com.itextpdf.signatures.PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = signer.getSignatureAppearance();
    appearance.setPageRect(new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0));
    appearance.setPageNumber(1);
    appearance.setReason("For test");
    appearance.setLocation("HKSAR");
    signer.setFieldName(fieldname);

    PreSignatureContainer external = new PreSignatureContainer(PdfName.Adobe_PPKLite, PdfName.Adbe_pkcs7_detached);
    signer.signExternalContainer(external, 8192);

    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(external.getHash());
}

public static class PreSignatureContainer implements IExternalSignatureContainer {

    private final PdfDictionary sigDic;
    private byte[] hash;

    public PreSignatureContainer(PdfName filter, PdfName subFilter) {
        sigDic = new PdfDictionary();
        sigDic.put(PdfName.Filter, filter);
        sigDic.put(PdfName.SubFilter, subFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] sign(InputStream data) throws GeneralSecurityException {
        String hashAlgorithm = "SHA256";
        BouncyCastleDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
        try {
            byte[] hash = DigestAlgorithms.digest(data, digest.getMessageDigest(hashAlgorithm));
            this.hash = hash;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new GeneralSecurityException("PreSignatureContainer signing exception", e);
        }
        return new byte[0];
    }

    @Override
    public void modifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic) {
        signDic.putAll(sigDic);
    }

    public byte[] getHash() {
        return hash;
    }
}

inclusion of the signature in the prepared Container
public String getSignedContent(String tempPdfPath, JSONObject jsonObject) throws IOException {
    PdfReader reader = null;
    try {
        // Obtém o valor de "signedContent" diretamente do JSON
        String signedContentBase64 = jsonObject
                .getJSONObject("data")
                .getJSONArray("signatures")
                .getJSONObject(0) // Primeiro (e único) objeto
                .getString("signedContent");

        // Decodificar o conteúdo assinado de Base64
        byte[] signedContent = Base64.getDecoder().decode(signedContentBase64);

        // Certificado do JSON para validar a assinatura
        String encodedCertificate = jsonObject
                .getJSONObject("data")
                .getJSONObject("certificateInformation")
                .getString("encodedX509");

        byte[] certificateBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(
                encodedCertificate.replace("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----", "")
                        .replace("-----END CERTIFICATE-----", "")
                        .replace("\n", "")
        );

        // Criar um objeto X509Certificate a partir dos dados do certificado
        CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        X509Certificate certificate;
        try (ByteArrayInputStream certInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(certificateBytes)) {
            certificate = (X509Certificate) certFactory.generateCertificate(certInputStream);
        }

        reader = new PdfReader(tempPdfPath);
        byte[] signedPdfBytes;

        try (ByteArrayOutputStream signedPdfOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            // Criar um PdfSigner para o PDF assinado
            PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, signedPdfOutputStream, new StampingProperties());

            // Criar um contêiner PKCS7
            PdfPKCS7 pkcs7 = new PdfPKCS7(null, new X509Certificate[]{certificate}, "SHA256", null, new BouncyCastleDigest(), false);
            pkcs7.setExternalDigest(signedContent, null, "RSA");

            // Obter o pacote PKCS7
            byte[] pkcs7Bytes = pkcs7.getEncodedPKCS7(null, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS, null, null, null);

            // Usar signDeferred para assinar o campo de assinatura existente
            // Criar um contêiner de assinatura que implemente IExternalSignatureContainer
            IExternalSignatureContainer external = new MyExternalSignatureContainer(pkcs7Bytes);

            String fieldName = "Signature1"; // Nome do campo de assinatura existente
            PdfSigner.signDeferred(signer.getDocument(), fieldName, signedPdfOutputStream, external);

            // Obter os bytes do PDF assinado
            signedPdfBytes = signedPdfOutputStream.toByteArray();
        }

        // Codificar o PDF assinado em Base64 e retornar
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(signedPdfBytes);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Erro ao processar o JSON ou assinar o PDF: " + e.getMessage());
        return null; // Retorna nulo em caso de erro
    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            reader.close();
        }
        // Apagar o arquivo temporário
        File tempFile = new File(tempPdfPath);
        if (tempFile.exists()) {
            tempFile.delete();
        }
    }
}

private static class MyExternalSignatureContainer implements IExternalSignatureContainer {

    private final byte[] pkcs7Bytes;

    public MyExternalSignatureContainer(byte[] pkcs7Bytes) {
        this.pkcs7Bytes = pkcs7Bytes;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] sign(InputStream data) {
        return pkcs7Bytes;
    }

    @Override
    public void modifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic) {
        // Implementação do método de modificação do dicionário de assinatura
    }
}

JSON that can be obtained from the user certificate data Would having this information before signing help in any way?
{
  "data": {
      
    "credentialId": "string",
            
    "executionStatus": {
      "currentStatus": "PENDING_SIGNATURE",
      "requestTimestamp": "2019-08-24T14:15:22Z",
      "executionTimestamp": "2019-08-24T14:15:22Z"
    },
        
    "subjectIdentification": {
      "identificationKey": "string",
      "identificationType": "CPF"
    },

    "certificateInformation": {
        
        "serialNumber": "string",
        "issuerName": "string",

        "validity": {
            "notBefore": "1977-01-01T00:00:00Z",
            "notAfter": "1977-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },

        "subjectName": "string",
        "encodedX509": "string",
        "fingerprint256": "string"
    }    
  }
}

On some machines, when opening the PDF it displays this warning
On some machines, when opening the PDF it displays this warning
"The identity of the signer is unknown because it has not been included in your list of trusted identities and none of the parent certificates is a trusted certificate"
here is the output for PDFSIG of a PDF that is displayed without any warning.
NSS_Init failed: security library: bad database.

Digital Signature Info of: signed.pdf
Signature #1:

Signature Field Name: 25e8a269-03a8-4685-ae26-3e746805c0f3@validpsc
Signer Certificate Common Name: GESIANE DA SILVA LOUREDO:10469981709
Signer full Distinguished Name: CN=GESIANE DA SILVA LOUREDO:10469981709,OU=33583550000130,OU=Presencial,OU=AR CFM,OU=AC VALID RFB V5,OU=RFB e-CPF A3,OU=Secretaria da Receita Federal do Brasil - RFB,O=ICP-Brasil,C=BR
Signing Time: Nov 14 2023 06:03:11
Signing Hash Algorithm: SHA-256
Signature Type: ETSI.CAdES.detached
Signed Ranges: [0 - 1223818], [1327786 - 1329701]
Total document signed
Signature Validation: Signature is Valid.
Certificate Validation: Certificate issuer isn't Trusted.

and here is the output of the PDF that has been signed by the upadte 1 code
NSS_Init failed: security library: bad database.

Digital Signature Info of: laudo_signed.pdf
Signature #1:

Signature Field Name: Signature1
Signer Certificate Common Name: GESIANE DA SILVA LOUREDO:10469981709
Signer full Distinguished Name: CN=GESIANE DA SILVA LOUREDO:10469981709,OU=33583550000130,OU=Presencial,OU=AR CFM,OU=AC VALID RFB V5,OU=RFB e-CPF A3,OU=Secretaria da Receita Federal do Brasil - RFB,O=ICP-Brasil,C=BR
Signing Time: Dec 09 2024 10:34:35
Signing Hash Algorithm: SHA-256
Signature Type: adbe.pkcs7.detached
Signed Ranges: [0 - 141], [16527 - 73936]
Total document signed
Signature Validation: Signature is Valid.
Certificate Validation: Certificate issuer is unknown.

I am sending both PDFs for review
PDF created with update 1 code
No Warning PDF
Update 2
This would be a complete json when a call is made to get the user's credentials. This call can be made before signing, so we would be able to access the certificate. How would it be possible to include the entire certificate chain to make the certificate completely valid?
{

"data": {
"credentialId": "01JERJKX21PRNP0VN8VVV1C6WC",
"currentTimestamp": "2024-12-10T15: 23: 41.101Z",
"expireTimestamp": "2024-12-11T03: 23: 40.979Z",
"executionsStatus": {
"currentStatus": "PENDING_SIGNATURE",
"requestTimestamp": "2024-12-10T15: 23: 40.979Z"
},
"subjectIdentification": {
"identificationKey": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"identificationType": "CPF"
},
"certificateInformation": {
"serialNumber": "51AD3A27FFEA6DB6",
"issuerName": "C=BR\nO=ICP-Brasil\nOU=Secretaria da Receita Federal do Brasil - RFB\nCN=AC VALID RFB v5",
"validity": {
"notBefore": "Dec 10 12: 49: 47 2024 GMT",
"notAfter": "Dec 10 12: 49: 47 2028 GMT"
},
"subjectName": "C=BR\nO=ICP-Brasil\nOU=Secretaria da Receita Federal do Brasil - RFB\nOU=RFB e-CPF A3\nOU=AC VALID RFB V5\nOU=AR VALID CD\nOU=Videoconferencia\nOU=14121957000109\nCN=: ",
"encodedX509": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIIH3zCCBcegAwIBAgIIUa06J //qbbYwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwdDELMAkGA1UE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\nd9IK\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n",
"fingerprint256": "36:F6:BA:18:88:CF:58:18:51:F6:21:DF:67:B4:A8:8A:E5:E5:69:FA:88:18:04:FB:3D:CA:8E:38:BA:31:DA:C8",
"subjectAlternatives": "email: xxx@yyy.com.br"
}
}
}
Update 3:
I was able to implement the inclusion of the certificate chain as per your suggestion. Here is the code I used to build the certificate chain from the AIA extension and incorporate it into the PDF signature.
Building the certificate chain:
// Method to build the certificate chain
private static List<X509Certificate> buildCertificateChain(X509Certificate certificate) throws Exception {
    List<X509Certificate> chain;
    X509Certificate currentCert = certificate;
    // Extract the AIA extension
    byte[] aiaExtension = currentCert.getExtensionValue("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1"); // AIA OID
    // Extract the CA issuer URI using BouncyCastle
    Optional<String> caIssuerURI = extractAIAUriUsingBC(aiaExtension);
    chain = downloadCertificateChain(caIssuerURI.get(), certificate);
    return chain;
}

// Method to extract the AIA URI using BouncyCastle
private static Optional<String> extractAIAUriUsingBC(byte[] aiaExtension) {
    try (ASN1InputStream asn1InputStream = new ASN1InputStream(aiaExtension)) {
        ASN1Primitive derObject = asn1InputStream.readObject();
        if (derObject instanceof DEROctetString) {
            derObject = ASN1Primitive.fromByteArray(((DEROctetString) derObject).getOctets());
        }
        AuthorityInformationAccess aia = AuthorityInformationAccess.getInstance(derObject);
        if (aia != null) {
            for (AccessDescription accessDescription : aia.getAccessDescriptions()) {
                if (X509ObjectIdentifiers.id_ad_caIssuers.equals(accessDescription.getAccessMethod())) {
                    GeneralName generalName = accessDescription.getAccessLocation();
                    if (generalName.getTagNo() == GeneralName.uniformResourceIdentifier) {
                        String uri = generalName.getName().toString();
                        return Optional.of(uri);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error processing AIA extension: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}

// Method to download the CA certificate chain
private static List<X509Certificate> downloadCertificateChain(String uri, X509Certificate certificat) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Downloading certificate from: " + uri);
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    URL url = new URL(uri);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    try (InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream()) {
        byte[] pkcs7Bytes = readAllBytesFromInputStream(inputStream);
        CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        Collection<? extends Certificate> certificates;
        try {
            certificates = certFactory.generateCertificates(new ByteArrayInputStream(pkcs7Bytes));
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            throw new CertificateException("Error processing the PKCS#7 file.", e);
        }
        List<X509Certificate> certificateChain = new ArrayList<>();
        certificateChain.add(certificat);
        for (Certificate cert : certificates) {
            if (cert instanceof X509Certificate) {
                certificateChain.add((X509Certificate) cert);
            }
        }
        if (certificateChain.isEmpty()) {
            throw new CertificateException("No certificates found in the PKCS#7 file.");
        }
        System.out.println("Certificates downloaded and processed successfully.");
        return certificateChain;
    }
}

// Helper method to read all bytes from an InputStream
private static byte[] readAllBytesFromInputStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] data = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
        buffer.write(data, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    return buffer.toByteArray();
} 

Execution snippet:
CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
X509Certificate certificate;
try (ByteArrayInputStream certInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(certificateBytes)) {
    certificate = (X509Certificate) certFactory.generateCertificate(certInputStream);
}
// Build the certificate chain
List<X509Certificate> certificateChain = buildCertificateChain(certificate);
// Create a PKCS7 container with the full chain
PdfPKCS7 pkcs7 = new PdfPKCS7(null, certificateChain.toArray(new X509Certificate[certificateChain.size()]), "SHA256", null, new BouncyCastleDigest(), false);
pkcs7.setExternalDigest(signedContent, null, "RSA");
// Use signDeferred to sign the PDF
IExternalSignatureContainer external = new MyExternalSignatureContainer(pkcs7.getEncodedPKCS7(null, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS, null, null, null));
PdfSigner.signDeferred(signer.getDocument(), "Signature1", signedPdfOutputStream, external);

Now, the generated PDF includes the entire certificate chain, making the signature fully valid. Thank you for the help; it was crucial in solving the problem!
One final question: In the generated PDF, the signature is not enabled for LTV (Long-Term Validation). Is there any way to handle this to ensure the signature remains valid over time?
pdfSig output for complete pdf
NSS_Init failed: security library: bad database.
Digital Signature Info of: complete_pdf.PDF
Signature #1:

Signature Field Name: Signature1
Signer Certificate Common Name: GABRIEL REGINATTO DE SOUZA MENEZES:14535185760
Signer full Distinguished Name: CN=GABRIEL REGINATTO DE SOUZA MENEZES:14535185760,OU=14121957000109,OU=Videoconferencia,OU=AR VALID CD,OU=AC VALID RFB V5,OU=RFB e-CPF A3,OU=Secretaria da Receita Federal do Brasil - RFB,O=ICP-Brasil,C=BR
Signing Time: Dec 10 2024 16:49:15
Signing Hash Algorithm: SHA-256
Signature Type: adbe.pkcs7.detached
Signed Ranges: [0 - 141], [16527 - 73936]
Total document signed
Signature Validation: Signature is Valid.
Certificate Validation: Certificate issuer isn't Trusted.

Complete PDF (Update 3)

"Receive the signature data: The service returns a JSON containing the signed hash (signedContent), the certificate (encodedX509) and other information." - The common examples expect you to have hold of the certificate already before requesting the signature. If you don't have it before that, you cannot have a signature visualization built from certificate data in the document, and you cannot create signatures with an advanced profile, like PAdES signatures. Thus, are you sure you cannot retrieve the certificate before signing?

@mkl Thanks for the answer and help. Right after posting the question I was able to sign it. The code is in UPDATE 1. Regarding the certificate data, there is in fact an endpoint that allows you to obtain certificate data. I posted the JSON as an update to the question.
I also included two PDFs, one signed by the old version of the API, in which you sent the PDF in base 64 and they returned a signed PDF, and the PDF generated by the code in update 1.

Comparing laudo_signed.pdf and signed.pdf
The signatures, in particular the embedded CMS signature containers, are very different.
Embedded certificates
The difference that causes the

message is that the laudo_signed.pdf signature container only contains the signer certificate while the signed.pdf signature container contains the full certificate chain from the signer certificate to the root Autoridade Certificadora Raiz Brasileira v5 certificate.
Thus, a validator analyzing the signed.pdf signature can immediately build the certificate path to the root certificate and - if it trusts that root - knows that it can trust the signer identity while a validator analyzing the laudo_signed.pdf signature must either have the intermediary certificates to the root installed locally or retrieve them online.
Adobe Acrobat usually does retrieve such missing intermediary certificates online but fails to do so here. I'm not sure, why it fails. The signer certificate does contain an AIA extension with a CA issuer entry. Acrobat might not accept this because one retrieves a CMS certificate collection from the URI value of that entry while most often CA issuer entries point to single certificates.
So the computers that do trust the signer certificate in laudo_signed.pdf appear to have installed the intermediary certificates locally, while those that don't appear to have not.
To prevent this issue, you can retrieve the whole certificate chain using the AIA entry of the signer certificate once you have that and then embed the whole certificate chain, too.
Other differences
The laudo_signed.pdf signature is a adbe.pkcs7.detached signature with a minimalistic signature container without any signed attributes while the signed.pdf signature is an ETSI.CAdES.detached PAdES signature with the signed attributes required for PAdES signatures and also a signature policy signed attributes.
Whether your minimalistic signature container suffices, depends on the requirements of the validation policy for the Autoridade Certificadora Raiz Brasileira v5 CA. For EU qualified signatures it would not suffice.
Other questions
Certificate information available before signing

JSON that can be obtained from the user certificate data Would having this information before signing help in any way?

As already mentioned above you can retrieve the certificate chain once you have the certificate, and for your minimalistic signature containers it suffices to do that after the signing call to the API.
If you want to change your code to create signature containers with ESS signingCertificate[V2] entries, though: The information in that JSON excerpt is somewhat redacted, so I cannot tell for sure. The name of the encodedX509 field, though, creates the impression that it might contain the signer certificate. If that is the case, this information would indeed help.
Embedding the entire certificate chain
(from comments)

How would it be possible to include the entire certificate chain to make the certificate completely valid?

When you have the certificate, parse it (using basic Java or BouncyCastle classes) and retrieve its AIA extension CA issuer value which is an URI.
Download the file from that URI. In general this either is a single certificate or a CMS signature container carrying only certificates.
Complete the certificate chain. If not completed, select the certificate at its current end and retrieve its AIA extension CA issuer value etc etc
LTV-enabling the signature

In the generated PDF, the signature is not enabled for LTV (Long-Term Validation). Is there any way to handle this to ensure the signature remains valid over time?

Acrobat considers a PDF signature "LTV-enabled" if all data (except trust anchors) required for validation are contained in the PDF. This in particular means all used certificates with revocation information (CRLs and/or OCSP responses) unless they are trust anchors or otherwise marked to not require revocation information.
"All used certificate" here not only means the certificate chain of the main signer certificate but also the certificate chains of the CRL or OCSP response signers.
There are two main options how to include all these data:

Adobe signed RevocationInfoArchival attribute according to section 12.8.3.3.2 of ISO 32000-1 and ISO 32000-2
ETSI unsigned Document Security Store PDF objects according to section 5.4.2 of ETSI EN 319 142-1 and section 12.8.4.3 of ISO 32000-2

Which option is appropriate for you, depends on your requirements:

Is ISO 32000-1 compatibility relevant? Then use the former.
Is PAdES compatibility relevant? Then use the latter.

If you only care about validation by Acrobat, you can use either option.
You may want to take a look at the AdobeLtvEnabling class presented in this answer
Or you may want to consider updating to iText 9 which includes numerous extensions to the signing API, among them helpers to easily create PAdES baseline signatures, in particular PAdES B-LT signatures.

Thanks for the explanation. I included in update 2 a complete json of the API call to obtain the user's credentials. This call can be made before signing, so we would be able to access the certificate. How would it be possible to include the entire certificate chain to make the certificate completely valid?

@Wesley "How would it be possible to include the entire certificate chain to make the certificate completely valid?" - When you have the certificate, parse it (using basic Java or BouncyCastle classes) and retrieve its AIA extension CA issuer value which is an URI. Download the file from that URI. In general this either is a single certificate or a CMS signature container carrying only certificates. Complete the certificate chain. If not completed, select the certificate at its current end and retrieve its AIA extension CA issuer value etc etc

We were able to generate the PDF with the entire Chain. Your answers were essential for this. Now only the LTV warning remains. Is there a way to solve this? Code and PDF in update 3

"Now only the LTV warning remains. Is there a way to solve this?" - LTV-enabling really is a topic of its own. I've added some thoughts on that to the answer. But you also may want to take a look at the signing API you use. Maybe it offers some option to retrieve the needed validation data, too. In that case you'd merely need to embed that into the PDF. Otherwise you have to do something akin to a validation to know what extra data is needed.
